# Responsive CSS/HTML for Tablet or Mobile Device

Tags: html, css

I have created a landing page for a SharePoint site with graphics. I have noticed that when resizing the browser window to that of something like a tablet or mobile device, the page/graphics aren't responsive and adjusting to the sizing.

I came across a few posts in relation to my issue, but none were very helpful.

Here is my HTML/CSS:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.img_container {
    border: none;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #b3ab7d;
}
a:hover {
    color: #b3ab7d;
}
.background {
    background: #104723;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.img {
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.text{
  font-size: 70%;
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  color: #104723;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <h1><strong>G3G Controls</strong></h1>

</head>
<div class="center">
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/ACControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Access Control (AC)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/IAControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Identification & Authentication (IA)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/MPControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Media Protection (MP)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/PEControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Physical Protection (PE)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/SCControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">System & Communications Protection (SC)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/SIControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">System & Information Integrity (SI)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: css for a responsive image is `img { vertical-align: middle; border: 0; max-width: 100%; height: auto; }` . If an image is in a container of 70%, then you may change class `.img { width: 100%; }`

Comment: @bron, I tried that and it worked a little bit but not to the extent I intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `flexboxes` that was enough to make stuff `responsive` the property you were lacking was setting a `flex-wrap:wrap` for the `.center` class which will let the images wrap to the next line as soon as the width of the container element reduces.

**Also**The `.img_container` for the images was creating an issue due to its `width:70%` and it also needs to be set to `display:flex` which will allow these images to accommodate side by side as you want. I also changed The container element `.center` `width` to 100%.

**The Proposed Code**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.img_container {
    display:flex;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #b3ab7d;
}
a:hover {
    color: #b3ab7d;
}
.background {
    background: #104723;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.text{
  font-size: 70%;
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.center {
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  color: #104723;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Topic</h1>
<div class="center">
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/ACControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Access Control (AC)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/IAControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Identification & Authentication (IA)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/MPControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Media Protection (MP)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/PEControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">Physical Protection (PE)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/SCControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">System & Communications Protection (SC)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
    <a href="/SIControls.aspx" class="btn">
    <div class="background">
        <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg/1024px-Angular_one_color_inverse_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" />
        <span class="text">System & Information Integrity (SI)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

**One Important thing** - In your code snippet in the `HTML` you have declared a `<h1>` heading at the top inside a `<head>` tag. Pls don't do this `<head>` tag is always used outside the `<body>` element that too to declare **meta data** which doesn't supposed to be visible in the browser. Their are other `semantic tags` to use inside the `<body>` element and I think you might have got confused with `<header>` tag which can be used inside the `<body>` element.

**Do tell me whether I was of any Help :)**

Comment: This worked just fine, but now the text is no longer in the img_container

Comment: Is it possible to get the text back over the background image?

Comment: Yeah! you can do that using ``position`` property like this https://codepen.io/tsaxena4k/pen/RwRppzw  But It doesn't look that good.